# Error: cannot read property push of undefined when using .push on an empty array that is stored in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks "save" I need to collect all the data from inputs with a class of `input_product` and compile it to `data` with this format:

```
data = {param1:[{upc:'upc', value:'value'}, ... ], ... paramN: [ ... ]}
```

I tried doing this with the code below, but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
$('.save').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = {};

  $('.input_product').each(function() {

    const
    param = $(this).attr('name'),
    upc = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'),
    value = $(this).val()

    console.log(param, upc, value); //prints qty, 1001, 5

    if (value && param) {
       if (!param in data) {
           data[param] = [];
       }
       data[param].push({'upc':upc, 'value':value}); // Error is thrown here
    }
  });
 window.someFunction(data);
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: When the error happens, what are the contents of `data` and `param`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator has lower precedence than the `!` operator. You need to add brackets around `param in data`; change

```
if(!param in data)
```

to

```
if(!(param in data))
```

Currently, what you are doing is converting the value of `param` to a boolean, negating that, and then checking if the result of that negation exists as a key in the object `data` (i.e., what you are writing is equivalent to `if((!param) in data)`) , when instead you want to check if `param` exists as a key in `data` and then negate the result of that to execute some code if `param` does not exist as a key in `data`. As a result, you are never setting the value of the key `param` in `data`, so it stays at `undefined` and you get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Try this:

```
$('.save').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = {};

  $('.input_product').each(function() {

    const
    param = $(this).attr('name'),
    upc = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'),
    value = $(this).val()

    console.log(param, upc, value);

    if (value && param) {
       if (!(param in data)) {//added brackets
           data[param] = [];
       }
       data[param].push({'upc':upc, 'value':value}); 
    }
  });
 window.someFunction(data);
});
```

Working JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n6bg3da8/